# Java ResultSet slows down SQLite In-Memory database

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, in-memory-database

I am using SQLite as an In-Memory database in my Java program using the sqlite-jdbc driver.

The query I am using is rather complex. Nevertheless, it is pretty fast with usually < 10 ms.
Unfortunately, iterating the ResultSet afterwards is rather costly, even with a large fetch size:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.setFetchSize(1000);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

System.out.println("query time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();

System.out.println("metadata time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

HashMap<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (rs.next())
{
    System.out.println("get records time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {

        if (metaData.getColumnName(i) != null && rs.getObject(i) != null)
        {
            record.put(metaData.getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i).toString());
        }
    }
    al.add(record);
}
System.out.println("all time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

The output of this little program shows where the time is consumed:

```
query time 5
metadata time 5
get records time 5
get records time 5
get records time 6
get records time 6
get records time 15
get records time 15
get records time 26
get records time 26
all time 52
```

I know that if the fetch size is too small, the ResultSet usually goes via network to the DB to move the cursor and get more data. However, in my case the fetch size is fairly large (1000), the DB is in memory and the result set contains a small amount of entries (<20).

Any ideas what I can do to make it faster? Does anybody know how SQLite handles selects?

Thanks in advance.
Sebastian

Comment: A larger fetch size is not necessarily better for performance (eg take into account the additional memory allocation and garbage collection required), and for an sqlite in-memory database considerations like network latency are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database and does not do any network communication; it computes result records on the fly and ignores the fetch size.

If your query is complex, searching and computing the next record will be relatively slow.

Comment: I should not have used the term "network". I certainly was aware of the fact that network is not required in the context of in-memory databases.

Comment: The problem was indeed the complexity of the query and, most importantly, the bad execution plan of SQLite. Using CROSS JOINS (= STRAIGHT JOINS in MySQL) I could circumvent this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is very inefficient. Instead of re-retrieving the column names each time, do this:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(i));
}
```

Then you can simplify the original `for` loop into this (this is assuming that your column names aren't `null`, which they never should be):

```
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
{
    Object cellObject = rs.getObject(columnNames.get(i));
    if( cellObject != null )
        record.put(cellObject.toString());
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're calling `al.add(record);` each time, when `record` is always pointing to the same `HashMap` (which in turn is being overwritten each time you go through the `while` loop). Take a careful look at how you're using `record`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was just a quick hack to have some example code. The actual problem was not the access of the meta data and the for-loop but the rs.next() statement. Further this is slow due to the complex query and the bad execution plan of SQLite.